# cakephp and imagick - raw files won't upload

Tags: php, cakephp, imagick

When I upload a JPEG everything works just fine. However, when upload a RAW it does work.  I have the php.ini upload limits set to 25M.  I was able to upload a 7MB JPEG file but not a 7MB RAW file.  Below is the error I am recieving:

```
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty wand' in /home/photobound/public_html/plugins/photo_bank/models/photo_bank_image.php:264, referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/photobound/public_html/plugins/photo_bank/models/photo_bank_image.php(264): Imagick->getimagewidth(), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /home/photobound/public_html/plugins/photo_bank/models/photo_bank_image.php(124): PhotoBankImage->computeImageFieldsForSave(), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /usr/share/php/cake/cakephp/cake/libs/model/model.php(1282): PhotoBankImage->beforeSave(Array), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /home/photobound/public_html/plugins/photo_bank/controllers/photo_bank_images_controller.php(131): Model->save(Array), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 [internal function]: PhotoBankImagesController->upload('-1'), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #5 /usr/share/php/cake/cakephp/cake/dispatcher.php(204): call_user_func_array(Array, Array), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #6 /usr/share/php/cake/cakephp/cake/dispatcher.php(171): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(PhotoBankImagesController), Array), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #7 /home/photobound/public_html/webroot/index.php(84): Dispatcher->dispatch(), referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr: #8 {main}, referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
[Wed Aug 17 17:23:55 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.6] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/photobound/public_html/plugins/photo_bank/models/photo_bank_image.php on line 264, referer: http://photobound.local/photo_bank/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf
```

Here is the code on line 264:

```
$this->data['PhotoBankImage']['width'] = $this->image->getImageWidth();
```

Here are my php.ini settings that I thought were relevent:

```
post_max_size = 25M
post_max_size = 25M
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
```

I'd appreciate any help, let me know if you need anything else from me in order understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

RAW files are not standard images. Standard graphics libraries are not going to be able to work with them. The format varies depending on camera make/model, etc.

Comment: imagick has support for RAW files of all types. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php